# VBA Excel Transform to loop

Tags: vba, excel

Here i have my hundred line of code please enlighten me about how do i put line code into loop
 here is my try but i wont work out still trying

```
 If sp.Name Like "Rounded Rectangle*" Or sp.Name Like "Oval*" Then


        For i = 11 To 100

        x = i - 9

        Sheet2.Shapes.Range(Array("Rounded Rectangle " + i)).TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet1.Range("A" + x)

        Next i


    End If
```

and repeat until X = 110

in this case how can i change it in to correct loop  please advice

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a general approach to making a loop to cover a string variable....say we want to loop over **Shape("Rectangle 1")....Shape("Rectangle 2")....Shape("Rectangle 3).....** , etc.

```
Dim str As String, i As Long
For i = 11 To 100
    str = "Rectangle " & CStr(i)
    Sheets2.Shapes(str)................
Next i
```

and use a similar approach to make "A2"..."A3".........

Comment: Sub Adjust()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sp As Shape
    Set ws = Sheet2
    For Each sp In ws.Shapes
    
        If sp.Name Like "Rounded Rectangle*" Or sp.Name Like "Oval*" Then
                 
        Dim strs As String
        Dim str As String, i As Long
        
For i = 11 To 100
    str = "Rectangle " & CStr(i)
    strs = CStr(i - 9)
    
    Sheet2.Shapes.Range(str).TextFrame.Characters.Text = Sheet1.Range("A" & strs)
Next i         
        
            
           
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

simple math:

```
For i = 11 To 100
```

change to

```
For i = 11 To 119
```